# Dispersion of Lithium Ions in Nature (Ratio Similar to Isotopes?)

Tags: ions, isotope

I'm working on a project that identifies average characteristics of different elements. I'm stuck on lithium, I can't find a way to ratio lithium I and lithium II that symbolizes how it is in nature. I tried looking around on the internet but I haven't found any mention of ratios to ions only ratios to isotopes. Does anyone know of anything that might help?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. If this means anything I could use the ratio in plasma conditions.

Comment: Alright I'm very frustrated, not with this site but with my project, does anyone out there know or understand how lithium ions are dispersed in nature?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after.  Are you trying to find  $\ce{Li+:Li2+}$?  It's going to be nearly infinite (or nearly zero, if you reverse it.)  Aside from in plasmas, lithium is almost always in the +1 oxidation state.

Comment: The reference to isotopes in the question is very confusing if you really are asking about the ratio of lithium(I) ions to lithium(II) ions.  Outside of high-energy plasmas, particle accelerators, or the vicinity of stellar cores, there aren't going to be many lithium(II) ions on Earth or in the universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I resolved my problem, the attributes I was looking at was spectra and combining the lines of both ions. The problem was I was comparing data given by two authors that used different units, so what I did, which I think solves my problem, was divide the sums of the given intensity by the emission probabilities for which I received the ratio of Li I to Li II as roughly 33 to 6 or 18% Lithium II. More than I or apparently anyone else thought so I may have still made a mistake, either way thanks to everyone who tried and helped.

Comment: Just to add, the resultant rgb value did match approximately with the hue of a common lithium flame test, so I am confident in my answer, thanks again. I need to start using stack exchange more often.